# Difference between (float *) & *(float*) in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am trying to understand the pointer concepts in-depth.
In the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *iptr = &i;
    printf("(float)* : %f\n", (float)*iptr);
    printf("(float*) : %f\n", (float*)iptr);
    printf("*(float*) : %f\n", *(float*)iptr);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 (float)* : 10.000000
 (float*) : 10.000000
*(float*) : 0.000000
```

I also got a warning for the type-cast `(float*)`.
I find it difficult to even analyse the difference. If anyone can help me to analyse what is the exact usage of all three, it would be helpful.

Comment: The second `printf()` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @iharob Yeah it should, specifier mismatches (and aliasing violations) are undefined behaviour but not constraint violations

Comment: It had compiled with a warning message @iharob

Comment: Denise, you have to get the `printf` format specifiers right on your own , otherwise you get garbage. It doesnt automatically detect and convert for you. For this example you need to change the `%f` on the second line to `%p`. Then we can go on to discuss the output

Comment: Then, Do not ignore warning messges!!!!!!

Comment: Yeah its done now @MattMcNabb. Now, the warning is removed.Thank you

Comment: Here after will take warnings too in account, thanks. @iharob

Comment: @Denise there is a reason why `-Werror` flag exists.

Comment: @Denise do not edit the original question if that invalidates already posted answers.

Comment: @iharob disagree - I advised the question to be edited :P  The real question is "Difference between `(float *)` & `*(float*)` in C", not "format specifier mismatch UB". You can update your answer

Comment: @MattMcNabb Although it's true, I believe it was one issue with this particular question which my answer tries to fix, and there was a comment on my answer saying that point 2 is wrong because the OP used `"%p"`.

Comment: @iharob consider un-rollbacking; imho the typo is just a pointless distraction from the main question being asked, because the output does not show anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is

1. You are dereferencing the `int` and casting it to `float` in

   ```
   printf("(float)* : %f\n", (float)*iptr);
   ```

   which is fine.
2. You are casting the `int` pointer to a `float` pointer, and printing the `float` pointer with the `"%f"` specifier is undefined behavior, the correct specifier for printing pointers is `"%p"`, so

   ```
   printf("(float*) : %f\n", (float*)iptr);
   ```

   is wrong, it should be

   ```
   printf("(float*) : %p\n", (void *) iptr);
   ```

   casting to `float *` here is not meaningful, because the `void *` address is the same as the `float *` address and also the `int *` address, the difference would be when you do pointer arithmetic.
3. You are casting the `int` pointer to a `float` and dereferencing the resulting `float` pointer, although it will [violate strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/1983495) in

   ```
   printf("(float*) : %f\n", *(float*)iptr);
   ```

   which is also undefined behavior

Comment: Still needs to cast it `void*` to match `%p`.

Comment: @iharob, understood till whatever you had explained. Even though it is undefined behavior, I did not get any errors or even warnings. I wonder how is that possible for " *(float*)ptr ". Is the address which iptr pointing before changed ? Could not exactly understand how I get 0.000000 for " *(float*) "

Comment: When undefined behavior happens, the behavior is _unpredictable_ and inexplicable.

Comment: Please refer the site : http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-quiz-pointers-addresses/ - question number : 3. They say it is not undefined behavior. @iharob

Comment: Whether it is undefined behavior or not, can anyone tell me how the value for (* (float* )) is always 0.000000

Comment: @Denise It doesn't matter what the site says, the standard does not specify a behavior in that case, and why it's always `0.000000` is not possible to know. Just for  the formattnig of the code at the link I just don't trust it, and the are breaking aliasing rules by doing something called [type punning](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html).

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct.

`i` is an `int` variable, and `iptr` a pointer to that `int`.

1. `(float)*iptr`: `*iptr` dereferences `iptr`, which returns an `int`. Then that `int` is converted to a temporary `float` containing the same value. And that `float` is used by `printf`.
2. `*(float*)iptr`: Attempts to cast a pointer-to-`int` into a pointer-to-`float`. This is invalid, and should produce a compiler warning or error. It creates a pointer with the same address, but with the type saying that it points to a `float` value.

   The `*` operator then dereferences it, so the `int` is read as if it were a `float`. So the resulting `float` would be invalid, and it could result in a segfault because `float`s are longer than `int`s, so it reads more memory than there is allocated for the `int`.
3. `(float*)iptr`: Same problem, but it doesn't dereference the (invalid) pointer, and passes a pointer-to-`float` into `printf`, instead of a `float`. But `printf` expects a `float`. Some compilers should also produce a warning/error here because the format string indicates what value types are expected.

   If the format specifier indicates `%p`, it expects a pointer (`void*`, `float*`, or any other). It will then print out the address, and not the value it points to. This can be useful in debugging for example.

Comment: The warning the compiler generates on the 2nd printf is: `warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float *' [-Wformat=]` this warning doesn't mean that is incorrect the conversion from `int *` to `float *`, but that printf expects a float value and not a pointer value. The compiler is only saying that the parameter is not of the same type that is declared in the format string.

Comment: But for *(float*)iptr - I found no error or even a warning message regarding the same and it prints 0.000000 (for %f) (might be the default val of the float as per my knowledge) @tmlen

Comment: @tmlen. ... In other words, if (in the 2nd `printf`) you use `%p` instead of `%f` the compiler gives no warning, although, in this case, the declaration `(float *)` has no sense! ... Then the problem is not the undefined behaviour; undefined behaviour may affect an eventual assignment I.E.: (relevant to the code in the question) `i=*(float *)iptr;`, but the compiler doesn't signal any warning!

Comment: For a code like `int i = 10; float f = *(float*)&i`;, the variable `f` will not contain `10.0f`, because it never converts the int value to a float value. It just reads the binary int value in memory as if it were a float. What value `f` then represents is undefined behavior, depends on how floats are encoded.
C allows for explicit pointer casts (`(float*)iptr`), but not implicit pointer casts (`float* fptr = iptr`). In some cases they are useful, for example if you have a function that takes a `void*` argument, and you know it actually is a pointer to an `int`. For example `qsort`.

Comment: @tmlen, Nothing to say about this! I'm saying something different!